# error during the compilation of a source code: No such file or directory

Tags: compilation, kernel

I am getting an error during compilation of a source code. I searched it but fail to find name of package which fix the problem.

> Error
>
> ls: cannot access /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/source: No such file or directory

**source code of make file**

```
# Makefile for bcm_wimax module
# Customized for ZTE AX226
# Makefile recreated be Minhazul Haq Shawon

KERNEL_VER  := $(shell uname -r)
KDIR        := /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VER)/build
KSRC        := /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VER)/source
INSTALL_DIR :=  /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VER)/kernel/drivers/staging/bcm/
TARGET_DRV  := bcm_wimax
EXTRAFLAGS  := -Wall O=$(KDIR)
PWD:= $(shell pwd)

obj-m = $(TARGET_DRV).o

$(TARGET_DRV)-objs :=InterfaceDld.o InterfaceIdleMode.o         InterfaceInit.o InterfaceRx.o \
        InterfaceIsr.o InterfaceMisc.o InterfaceTx.o \
        CmHost.o IPv6Protocol.o Qos.o Transmit.o\
        Bcmnet.o DDRInit.o HandleControlPacket.o\
        LeakyBucket.o Misc.o sort.o Bcmchar.o hostmibs.o            PHSModule.o\
        led_control.o nvm.o vendorspecificextn.o

default:
    $(MAKE) $(EXTRAFLAGS) -C $(KSRC) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

    rm -f *.o *.mod.* .*.cmd
install:
    cp $(TARGET_DRV).ko $(INSTALL_DIR)
clean:
    find . -name \*.o -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
    find . -name .\*.o.cmd -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
    find . -name \*.*~ -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
    find . -name \*.*.bak -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
    rm -f *.ko *.o *.mod.* .*.cmd
    rm -fr .tmp_versions
    rm -rf Module.symvers
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have the kernel source. Is this your first time compiling a kernel module? Then try to follow this tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-module.html

Comment: thanks @Evert. I installed linux-source and linux-header. Now it is showing another error" make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/source'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/source'
make: *** [default] Error 2 "

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile kernel source first.